# Moment of inertia and polar ice caps

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

[image: The question in question!]

Could anyone explain what this question has to do with moment of inertia? I am struggling to even find a place to begin.

Comment: The problem doesn’t mention moment of inertia, but you have somehow realized that it is important. How did you realize this?

Comment: a) What is a day? What is the conserved quantity here?

Comment: c) How does the water level change when ice, initially floating on the water, melts? (Perhaps think about this first on the scale of a glass of ice water, then on the scale of an ice cap)

Comment: @G.Smith The question is probably asked in a lesson dealing with Moment of Inertia topic. That is why he realised it is important

Comment: There was a similar "Back of the Envelope" question in the American Journal of Physics, but using cars instead of ice.

Comment: It might be helpful to this site for the OP to present the question as TEXT and not as an IMAGE. (Useful tools to help you do this:  https://www.developertoolkits.com/ocr/image-to-text-converter   and  http://www.structurise.com/screenshot-ocr/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions to lead you towards the answer:

What is the moment of inertia of the Earth before the caps melt?

What is the moment of inertia of the Earth after the caps melt?

What do you expect to happen to the length of a day?  Why?

What law of physics lets you write an equation here?  (You only know a short list of actual physics laws so far, so run down them all if you don't know. I'm guessing you know F=ma, the third law, conservation of energy, conservation of momentum, conservation of angular momentum...) One of those applies.

You have guessed that moment of inertia is relevant.  What formulas use it?

Think about those before you continue reading...

Okay, the main idea here is angular momentum is conserved.  The angular momentum can be written as $I\omega$ and we have a before and after situation, so $I_1\omega_1 = I_2\omega_2$. How is $\omega$ related to period?  How long is the period of the Earth's rotation?

Comment: I did realised the hints that you have gave me. I did set the equation you provided there at the end, and it did result in a change for the time, but it was small. In one of my steps, I calculated the additional length the shell of water would add to the radius of the earth using a formula relating the known volume of said shell and the sphere's radius and added radius to the earth. Then I used the period of the angular velocity to find the time for one revolution (a sidereal day). I got, in the end, an answer of $1*10^-5$ seconds for the question b. Hopefully that's the correct method.

Comment: That sounds about right!